# Can I force WordPress to use <i> instead of <em>?

Tags: html, html-editor

For example,

```
Did you know that <em>hot</em> was used to mean
"<a title="What is the origin of “hot” as “good-looking”
or “attractive”?" href="http://english.stackexchange.com/a/84227/1696">
sexually attractive</a>" as long ago as 1450? (Though it seems that
in earlier use, it more commonly meant "sexually attract<em>ed</em>".)
```

The second use of `<em>` in the above is correct: I want to *emphasise* the suffix *-ed*. However, the first use is incorrect. I want to use italic type to indicate the “use/mention distinction”. This is the proper preserve of the `<i>` tag. But WordPress autoconverts `<i>` to `<em>`. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: I think you mean in the Visual Editor? You can use <i> or <em> in the HTML Editor.  BTW ... <i> is not deprecated, but it is only a *style* tag now not for indicating text 'use/mention' see http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-I

Answer (score 6):

I am using the [plugin AddQuicktag](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/addquicktag/) from [@bueltge](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/170/bueltge) in some blogs to create a separate `<i>` button:

[image]

That creates a nice little button with the text **i!**, and WordPress will not touch it.