# How do I change TinyMCE button "i" to create a i tag rather than em?

Tags: hooks, tinymce, visual-editor, css, previews

I want to give the "italic" button back the "styling" behaviour, rather than the spammy `<em>`. I want that button to print a `<i>` tag, rather than `<em>`.

`<em>` tags became popular to spam search engines, but now I want it to be what it is: a styling feature to e.g. change the voice of the narration.

I've got a script to create my own styles, so I'll include the `<em`> tag there, to use it as what it **REALLY** is: **EMPHASIS**. I'll then style it accordingly (big, bold).

So now my problem is, I'm sure I can find the setting / string / parameter to hack in JavaScript, but... Do you know a way to hook it from / for WordPress?

Comment: Have you read http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66724/can-i-force-wordpress-to-use-i-instead-of-em?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function that will replace `<em>` with `<i>` on your post/page:

```
function replace_em_with_i($content) {
$content = str_replace('<em>', '<i>', $content);
$content = str_replace('</em>', '</i>', $content);
return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'replace_em_with_i');
```

**Warning:** I have tested the code to check if it works (and it does work), but you might want to do some serious testing before using it...

Using a similar function you can replace `<strong>` with `<b>`, and so on.

I hope this helps...

Comment: I do not think this is what the user wants - they clearly state that they wish to be able to use *both* tags, but have the editor button insert an `<i>` tag.